# PHP branching optimization and efficiency

Tags: php, mysql

I've come across problems like this numerous times and have always had a feeling that it's not the most efficient logic and I can't seem to find a straight answer:

In the event of needing to check a database based on certain criteria, and update the record if the match is true, while moving on to a different statement if the match is false, and finally inserting a new record if all database matches come back false, is there a more efficient way to optimize the current branching?

```
$id = *first query to look for id* //returns null if no match
if (is_null($_id)) { #no match
  $id = *fallback query looking for id *; -->returns null if no match
}
if (is_null($id)) {#still no match
  $id = *last fallback query looking for id*; -->returns null if no match
}


if (is_null($id)) { # no match was found, doesn't exist in DB so insert it
    //code to INSERT the new record
} else { #match was found
    //code to update the record*
}
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see your actual queries to provide a good answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using REPLACE INTO?

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient would be to run a single MySQL statement ...

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

This approach may not meet your use case, but eliminating the queries that check for the existence of a row improves performance. Just try to insert the row, and MySQL will reject it if it would violate a unique key constraint, no need to muck with checking using separate SELECT statements. If the attempt to insert the row raises a "duplicate key" exception, then the assignments specified in the `UPDATE` portion are performed.

This approach does require that the table have at least one unique constraint, beyond an AUTO_INCREMENT or system assigned surrogate key. Again, your use case may not meet this requirement, so this approach may not be suitable.

---

On another note: with the approach outlined in the question, there's potential for a race condition in a concurrent system. A client runs a SELECT to find a row, and runs a subsequent INSERT when it's not found. A second session could also look for the same row, and not find it, and also attempt to INSERT it.

The issue is that the database operation "check for a row and insert if it doesn't exist" isn't atomic, because there's multiple round trips.

```
 db session 1  - check if row exists, not found 
 db session 2  - check if row exists, not found
 db session 1  - insert the row - succeed
 db session 2  - insert the row - FAIL - because row already inserted
```

---

If we are stuck with the approach of running separate SELECT to find out if a "matching" row exists, then we could at least attempt to avoid multiple round trips to locate the row, by combining the queries that look for a matching row in a single statement; we should be able to at least get two separate SELECT statements combined with a UNION ALL, and we can return a discriminator column to distinguish which query returned a row.